# PdfRenderer on Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Does anyone know how to use the new PdfRenderer API on Android L?
This is what I have tried so far:

```
File file = new File(xyz.getAbsolutePath());
ParcelFileDescriptor fileDesc;
try {
        fileDesc = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDesc);
        final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
         for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
             Page page = renderer.openPage(i);
             BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(xyz.getAbsolutePath());
             page.render(bitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
             page.close();
         }
         renderer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do I get the bitmap required by page.render?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create the bitmap first then pass it to the page class. After you can page.render your bitmap will contain the pdf.